# Phantom CUPS printer in Linux Mint

Tags: linux, printer, cups

Is there a way to create a phantom CUPS printer in Linux Mint, which can print to a file?
I have a copy of the CUPS file for a networked Brother printer server, which I would like to emulate for testing.

Comment: See if this works for you: https://www.aplawrence.com/MacOSX/macosxcupstofile.html

Comment: Thanks. This is way above my programming pay grade. For now I will have to live with copy and paste.